# Blittable Vs. Non-Blittable in IL

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke, unmanaged, managed

I'm trying to make sure that my Managed to Unmanaged calls are optimized.  Is there a quick way to see by looking at the IL if any non-blittable types have accidentally gotten into my pinvoke calls?

I tried just writing two unmanaged functions in a .dll, one that uses bool (which is non-blittable) and one that uses ints.  But I didn't see anything different when looking at the IL to let me know that it was doing something extra to marshal the bool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no marshaling-related stuff in IL. Instead, you should analyze methods' parameter types (with modifiers) and return types following the rules described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx). These rules are fairly simple, it ought to be possible to write an automated checker and plug it into e.g. FxCop.

Answer (score 3):

Anton Tykhyy is right. Type analysis is what you need; searching through IL is not going to help you. I recommend the reading of the following articles to decide if you're doing it right.

- Blittable and Non-Blittable Types
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/75dwhxf7.aspx
- Copying and Pinning
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/23acw07k.aspx
- CLR Inside Out: Marshaling between Managed and Unmanaged Code
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc164193.aspx
- .NET Column: P/Invoke Revisited
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc163910.aspx
- An Overview of Managed/Unmanaged Code Interoperability
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

> There is no marshaling-related stuff
>   in IL.

Thats not true.

Even for 'bool' there may be a need for some marshaling to be done depending on how 'bool' is defined in the unmanaged language. For example, in MS C++ alone, there are two types 'bool' which is 1 byte and 'BOOL' which is 4 bytes. On the other hand, I think, .Net bool is 1 byte, so you may have to specify how to marshal it depending on the size of the unmanaged bool.

Comment: It seems like there must be something there.  Bool is listed specifically as non-blittable.  But I don't see anything unusual in the IL to indicate that any marshalling is going ok when I look at it.

Comment: So how is it in IL? Where does the assembly say `bool` is not blittable? Yes, there might be `MarshalAs` attributes, but 1) that's strictly speaking not IL and 2) neither absence nor presence of `MarshalAs` says anything about blittability — type analysis is what's required.